# Is it necessary to use 'weak' in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am a very beginner of iOS.

I am using Swift to program, and I only know Objective-C a little bit.

I know there is a keyword 'weak' in Objective-C, to prevent circular reference and out of memory.

But I don't know whether I should use it in Swift, and when?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use 'weak' wherever it makes sense and its usage is exactly similar to that in Objective C. Here are few examples where you need to be using weak:

1. In most cases for IBOutlets. For a good discussion on this ref:
   http://nshipster.com/ibaction-iboutlet-iboutletcollection/
2. Make the delegate object references as weak
3. To ensure you don't have retain cycles in case where objects end up referring to each other.

Refer for a complete discussion on this topic at:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID52

Answer (score 1):

It works very much the same as in Objective-C too. Here's a detailed explanation from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html